# FindAsync returns null despite UserManager extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm currently working from this excellent guide for the purpose of migrating an existing web app that uses SQL Membership authentication to ASP.NET Identity authentication:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

**With the difference being** that I am not using a Web Forms project, so I've adapted it to work with an MVC 5 project. Here's my UserManager class, which is supposed to check for SQL Membership passwords and update them when necessary (see link above for details):

```
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyUserManager()
        : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        this.PasswordHasher = new SQLPasswordHasher();
    }
    public class SQLPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher
    {
        public override string HashPassword(string password)
        {
            return base.HashPassword(password);
        }

        public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
        {
            string[] passwordProperties = hashedPassword.Split('|');
[SNIP]
```

**The problem is** that the /Account/Login method does not seem to use the PasswordHasher extension. Here's the code (straight from the MVC 5 template, though the UserManager object is an instance of the MyUserManager class above):

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
[SNIP]
```

It won't authenticate. I imagine I'm not the only one trying to make this work. Any pointers? For MVC 5, do I need to write a different extension?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way this should be set up for a new MVC 5 project:

**IdentityModels.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationServices")
    {
    }
}

public class MyUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyUserManager()
        : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        this.PasswordHasher = new SQLPasswordHasher();
    }
    public class SQLPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher
[etc.]
```

The SQLPasswordHasher code can be found [here](https://github.com/suhasj/SQLMembership-Identity-OWIN/blob/master/SQLMembership-Identity-OWIN/SQLMembership-Identity-OWIN/IdentityModels/UserManager.cs).

**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
        : this(new MyUserManager())
    {
    }

    public AccountController(MyUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public MyUserManager UserManager { get; private set; }

[etc.]
```

The rest is exactly as it appears on the blog mentioned above and/or as it appears in the default MVC 5 template. Once hooked up to a context with SQL Membership info, it works like a charm. Hope this helps.